# Import data from utf8mb4 Table to utf8 Table in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, type-conversion

i imported fields and data from a utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci table to a table with utf8_general_ci fields

But when I go to print I see all the strange characters (in php). How do I convert these fields optimally?

i found this

```
UPDATE table SET title = CONVERT (CONVERT (CONVERT (title USING utf8mb4) USING binary) USING UTF8)
```

EDIT: IT WORK. But if I print like this in php I see the strange characters, I have to use utf8_encode to see everything normal. I wish I could do a good encode directly in mysql instead of using utf8_encode in php in all points of the application

Comment: Well the utf-8_ character set cannot support all the characters that utf8mb4_ can. So you will loose those characters which are not representable

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci unknown

Comment: *i don't know how to replace latin with `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` because it gives me error* Of course. This is a collation. According charset is `utf8mb4` - use this value.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but when i print with php i always see strange characters, i have to use utf8_encode to bring everything back to normal. How can I do to convert everything correctly in mysql without having to use utf_8encode in php? @Akina

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET utf8` is missing Emoji, some Chinese characters, and a few other things.  `utf8mb4` has those.  Why did you downgrade to "utf8"?  Start a new Question explaining what got this task started.

Comment: For strange characters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored